# Lambda expression:term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Tags: c++

I got this error:error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> ivec{ 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89 };
    vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator it = ivec.crbegin(), rend = ivec.crend();
    for_each(it, rend, [it]()->void {cout << *it << " "; });

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What wrong with these code?Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: `for_each` passes each element of `ivec` into the lambda, which you've made take no argument (the round brackets `()`). The square brackets, `[it]`, _implicitly_ copies the iterator on construction of the lambda (it only does this once, so it'll have a copy of the iterator to the last element only). To fix: `for_each(it, rend, [](int n){cout << n << " "; });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for_each` will pass `*it` to the lambda function as a reference, you do not need to capture the iterator and dereference it. The following code shows this in action:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> ivec{ 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89 };
    vector<int>::const_reverse_iterator it = ivec.crbegin(), rend = ivec.crend();
    for_each(it, rend, [](const int &i)->void {cout << i << " "; });

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is, as expected, the reversed vector:

```
89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1
```

---

For the language lawyers amongst us, this is covered in `[alg.foreach]` in the ISO standard (`C++20` is the one I'm looking at). See in particular note `2` (my emphasis) where it states, in a roundabout way, that the iterator is de-referenced and that value is passed to the function:

> `23.5.4 For each [alg.foreach]`
>
> `template<class InputIterator, class Function>`
> `constexpr Function for_each(`
>    `InputIterator first,`
>    `InputIterator last,`
>    `Function f);`
>
> 1. Requires: Function shall satisfy the `Cpp17MoveConstructible` requirements (Table 25). [Note: Function need not meet the requirements of `Cpp17CopyConstructible` (Table 26). — end note]
> 2. Effects: Applies `f` to the ***result of dereferencing every iterator*** in the range `[first, last)`, starting from `first` and proceeding to `last - 1`. [Note: If the type of first satisfies the requirements of a mutable iterator, `f` may apply non-constant functions through the dereferenced iterator. — end note]
> 3. Returns: `f`.
> 4. Complexity: Applies `f` exactly `last - first` times.
> 5. Remarks: If `f` returns a result, the result is ignored